# Intersection Observer isVisible variable not changing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, intersection-observer

I have set up this Intersection Observer function because I want my divs to slide in from the side as the user scrolls down. However, after much tinkering and small changes, it still is not working. I've tried console-logging "entries", the "isVisible" variable, and "sliderRef". The first two are useless, as I get undefined for isVisible and an empty array for "entries", while I get the first div when I console-log sliderRef, but not the other two divs. I apologize for the vagueness and inability to present a specific reason as to why this isn't working. Any help would be appreciated, or any suggestion for a simpler way to achieve what I'm trying to do. Below is all the relevant code:

Edit: I changed the default value of isVisible to true, to see if the props were even being passed to my styled components, and the div appeared briefly on load but then slid out of view. However, still nothing happens when I have isVisible set to false. My options don't seem to be being taken into account, because the function was triggered regardless of the fact that I had not yet reached the threshold, which is 0.5

````
import { useRef, useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import {
  Container,
  Grid,
  Typography,
  makeStyles
} from '@material-ui/core';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    height: "200vh",  
    marginBottom: "200px"      
  },
  contentGrid: {
    display: "flex",
    height: "33%",
    padding: 0,
  }, 
}));

const useElementOnScreen = (options) => {
  const sliderRef = useRef(null);
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

  const callBackFunction = (entries) => {
    const [entry] = entries;
    setIsVisible(entry.IsIntersecting);
    console.log(entries);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callBackFunction, options);
    if (sliderRef.current) observer.observe(sliderRef.current);

    return () => {
      if (sliderRef.current) observer.unobserve(sliderRef.current);
    };
  }, [sliderRef, options]);

  return [sliderRef, isVisible];
}

function Features({ className, ...rest }) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [sliderRef, isVisible] = useElementOnScreen({
    root: null,
    threshold: 0.5,
    rootMargin: "0px 0px -100px 0px"
  })

  return (
    <div
      className={clsx(classes.root, className)}
      {...rest}
    >
      {/* <Container maxWidth="lg" style={{padding: 0, width: "100%"}}> */}
        <Grid className={classes.contentGrid} style={{backgroundColor: "#025373"}}>          
          <SliderFromLeft visible={isVisible}
          ref={sliderRef}
          style={{backgroundColor: "#F2D680"}}          
          >            
            <Typography
            variant="h4">
            Increased complexity has enabled media agencies 
            to create opaque financial structures 
            and then inflate their fees and 
            media prices at will, while many 
            advertisers are stuck behind contracts 
            unfit for modern media buying that 
            provide little scope for transparency and accountability.
            </Typography>
          </SliderFromLeft>
          <NonSlider style={{alignItems: "center", paddingRight:"75px"}}>
            <Typography 
            variant="h1"
            align="right"
            style={{color:"#F2C230", fontSize:"4rem"}}
            >
              Are you getting the most out of your contract?
            </Typography>
          </NonSlider>
        </Grid>
        <Grid className={classes.contentGrid} style={{backgroundColor: "#D0E5F2"}}>
          <NonSlider style={{backgroundColor: "#D0E5F2"}}>
            <Typography
            variant="h1"
            style={{color: "#025373", fontSize:"4rem"}}
            >
              The <br/>Challenge
            </Typography>
          </NonSlider>
          <SliderFromRight visible={isVisible}
          style={{backgroundColor: "#75B8BF"}}
          >
            <Typography
            variant="h4"
            style={{color:"#025373"}}>
            We want you to get the same benefits that the top global advertisers enjoy. 
            The core of a successful relationship between you and your media agency is a well thought-out contract.
            <br/>
            <br/>
            You must ensure that your media agency contract provides clarity and accountability, 
            and contains competitive terms and conditions.
            </Typography>
          </SliderFromRight>
        </Grid>
        <Grid className={classes.contentGrid} style={{backgroundColor: "#F2D680"}}>
          <SliderFromLeft visible={isVisible}      
          style={{backgroundColor:"#F2F2F2"}}
          ref={sliderRef}
          >
          <Typography
            variant="h4">            
            It is known that most media agencies design their own contract templates to benefit 
            themselves and not you. We believe this needs to change and you need to regain control. 
            <br/>
            <br/>
            To assess the quality of your contract, you must first benchmark it against the industry average. 
            Once you know the the strengths and weaknesses of the contract, it is easier to 
            know what needs to be improved upon.
            </Typography>
          </SliderFromLeft>
          <NonSlider style={{alignItems: "center", justifyContent:"right", paddingRight: '75px'}}>
            <Typography 
            variant="h1"
            align="right"
            style={{color:"#025373", fontSize:"4.2rem"}}
            >
              The <br/> Solution
            </Typography>
          </NonSlider>
        </Grid>
      {/* </Container> */}
    </div>
  );
}

const SliderFromLeft = styled.div`
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 75px 0 75px;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
  opacity: 0%;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform 400ms ease-in, opacity 250ms ease-in;
  ${props => props.visible && `
    transform: translateX(0%);
    opacity: 100;`
  }
`
const SliderFromRight = styled.div`
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 75px 0 75px;
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: transform 400ms ease-in, opacity 250ms ease-in;
  ${props => props.visible && `
   transform: translateX(0%)
   opacity: 100;`
}
`
const NonSlider = styled.div`
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 75px 0 75px
`

Features.propTypes = {
  className: PropTypes.string
};

export default Features;```
````

Comment: The visibility of a HTML element is _not_ a part of your application's state: and attempting to do will introduce a functional-dependency loop (from your component code, to the real DOM, to the rendered document, back to your component code).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same issue, despite reorganizing and improving my code based on updated documentation, I didn't exactly solve my problem, but I did somewhat achieve the effect I was looking for. I'm still not sure what was causing the issue, but I decided to ditch the slide-in effect for a simple fade-in effect by changing the opacity, and that works just fine.

Based on the newer documentation I found and some other answers here on SO, you can just import the useInView hook instead of writing it out yourself, and you must call useInView separately for each component, instead of giving all components the same ref and calling useInView once. I hope this helps.

````
import { useRef, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { useInView } from 'react-intersection-observer';
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import {
  Container,
  Grid,
  Typography,
  makeStyles
} from '@material-ui/core';
import Contract from './Media/contract.png'
import Challenge from './Media/challenge.png'
import Presenter from './Media/presenter.png'

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    height: "175vh",      
  },
  contentGrid: {
    display: "flex",
    height: "33%",
    padding: 0,
  }, 
  header: {
    color: "#000000",
    fontSize: "2.5rem",
    marginBottom: "10px",
  },
  image: {
    height: "355px",
    width: "500px",
  }
}));

function Features({ className, ...rest }) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const { ref: ref1, inView: inView1 } = useInView({ threshold: 0.5 })
  const { ref: ref2, inView: inView2 } = useInView({ threshold: 0.5 })
  const { ref: ref3, inView: inView3 } = useInView({ threshold: 0.5 })

  console.log(inView2);

  return (
    <div
      className={clsx(classes.root, className)}
      {...rest}
    >
      {/* <Container maxWidth="lg" style={{padding: 0, width: "100%"}}> */}
        <Grid className={classes.contentGrid}>          
          <SliderFromLeft 
          visible={inView1}
          ref={ref1}                  
          >         
            <Typography 
            variant="h1"
            align="left"
            className={classes.header}            
            >
              Are you getting the most out of your contract?
            </Typography>   
            <Typography
            variant="h4">
            Increased complexity has enabled media agencies 
            to create opaque financial structures 
            and then inflate their fees and 
            media prices at will, while many 
            advertisers are stuck behind contracts 
            unfit for modern media buying that 
            provide little scope for transparency and accountability.
            </Typography>
          </SliderFromLeft>
          <NonSlider style={{alignItems: "center", paddingRight:"75px"}}>       
            <img src={Contract} className={classes.image} />   
          </NonSlider>
        </Grid>
        <Grid className={classes.contentGrid}>
          <NonSlider>        
            <img className={classes.image} src={Challenge} />    
          </NonSlider>
          <SliderFromRight 
          visible={inView2}        
          ref={ref2}
          >
            <Typography
            variant="h1"
            align="right"
            className={classes.header}            
            >
              The Challenge
            </Typography>
            <Typography
            variant="h4"            
            >        
            We want you to get the same benefits that the top global advertisers enjoy. 
            The core of a successful relationship between you and your media agency is a well thought-out contract.
            <br/>
            <br/>
            You must ensure that your media agency contract provides clarity and accountability, 
            and contains competitive terms and conditions.
            </Typography>
          </SliderFromRight>
        </Grid>
        <Grid className={classes.contentGrid}>
          <SliderFromLeft 
          visible={inView3}                
          ref={ref3}
          >
            <Typography 
            variant="h1"
            align="left"
            className={classes.header}          
            >
              The Solution
            </Typography>
            <Typography
              variant="h4">            
              It is known that most media agencies design their own contract templates to benefit 
              themselves and not you. We believe this needs to change and you need to regain control. 
              <br/>
              <br/>
              To assess the quality of your contract, you must first benchmark it against the industry average. 
              Once you know the the strengths and weaknesses of the contract, it is easier to 
              know what needs to be improved upon.
            </Typography>
          </SliderFromLeft>
          <NonSlider style={{alignItems: "center", justifyContent:"right", paddingRight: '75px'}}>    
            <img src={Presenter} className={classes.image} />        
          </NonSlider>
        </Grid>
      {/* </Container> */}
    </div>
  );
}

const SliderFromLeft = styled.div`
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  // display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 75px 75px 0 75px;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
  opacity: 0;
  // transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform 400ms ease-in, opacity 0.5s ease-in;
  ${props => props.visible && `
    // transform: translateX(0%);
    opacity: 100;`
  }
`
const SliderFromRight = styled.div`
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  // display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 75px 75px 0 75px;
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
  opacity: 0;
  // transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: transform 400ms ease-in, opacity 0.5s ease-in;
  ${props => props.visible && `
    // transform: translateX(0%)
    opacity: 100;`
}
`
const NonSlider = styled.div`
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 75px 0 75px
`

Features.propTypes = {
  className: PropTypes.string
};

export default Features;```
````